# Python - Select Button on web page to simulate login

Tags: python

Working on a python scriptie trying to simulate a login action.

There is a username and password input box, along with a request text box to pass through text. Finally, a submit button to perform the actual login and hit the app.

I have inspected the elements of the HTML and the Network when hitting the page to get the necessary info (i think) ..

userid:blahblah@blah.com
password:blah123
request:textgoeshere

Here is the information when I inspect the Submit button ..

```
input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Submit" onclick="doSubmit()"
```

Here is the current python code I have ..

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import sys

URL = 'https://somewebsite.com'

def main():
    # Start a session so we can have persistant cookies
    session = requests.session()

    # This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
    login_data = {
        'userid': 'blahblah@blah.com',
        'password': 'blah123',
        'request': 'textgoeshere',
        'submitButton': '()',
    }

    # Authenticate
    r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)

    # Try accessing a page that requires you to be logged in
    r = session.get('URL', data=login_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The end result is a 200 web response but it seems the login action is not occurring. Thanks for any input.

Kernel

Comment: Hidden input fields? CSRF token? Additionally, you have some indent errors if that's the actual code.

Comment: No token, sorry for indent issues is from copying it over, indentation is fine.

Comment: this isn't as simple as you're making it out to be. Try using selenium if you need to simulate a web browser action in Python.

Comment: Maybe some `JS` code plopping in - you might reveal the real url so that we can have a look.

Comment: @ToughKernel you need to *fix* your indentation errors in the pasted code, or your question isn't even valid. It's like asking "why do I get 4 when I do 4 * 9?"

Comment: Your actual problem is that there is Javascript code in the `dosubmit()` function. That's what happens when you click on the login button. You need to do whatever is happening inside that function.

Comment: Ok, I will use selenium and see what happens! Thanks Wayne, will give it a go.

Comment: Can you share the url?